# Fields added multipletimes Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, tabs

I am implementing tabs. I have five tabs. For each tab i am calling screen in following way. In
displayTab1() function i am calling another class, It is easily loading MyScreen class but problem is for first time it is showing me same fields two times and whenever i click on this tab same fields are added continously. I have used delete(tabArea);

```
         public VerticalFieldManager displayTab1() 
     {  MyScreen loadingScreen = new MyScreen(); 
       tab1Manager.add(loadingScreen); 
         return tab1Manager;
      }
```

Please let me know where i am doing wrong
[image: This is view when tabs appears for second time after then when i navigate between tabs buttons are added continously. For first time button are shown two times]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this, In onFocusChanged() i first deleted the whole fields of tab1 by using tabManager1.deleteAll() and after that i added.

Comment: please remember to **accept** your own answer with the checkmark next to this answer, so we know it has been solved.  thanks.